# Polymorphism in MATLAB Coder

Tags: matlab, polymorphism, matlab-coder

In MATLAB, inheriting from `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` for the base class will allow nice polymorphism. However, it appears this isn't supported in Coder. First, can anyone confirm that Coder cannot use matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous, and if not, does anyone have a nice workaround?

For instance, I have the usual setup of an ABC called Shape, which is derived from both handle and matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous. Then I have Rectangle and Circle derived from Shape. I'd like to be able to have an array like:

```
classdef Shape < handle & matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
classdef Circle < Shape
classdef Rectangle < Shape
harray = [Rectangle(height, width), Circle(radius)];
```

In Matlab, harray becomes a type "`1x2 heterogeneous Shape (Rectangle, Circle) array`"

In Coder, I get the error "`Base class 'matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous' cannot be loaded.`" during the build.

Any ideas how this could be approached? Before I do something crazy, I just want to check if there's something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` is not supported for code generation. I reported your desire to use it and the unclear error message to the MATLAB Coder team.

Arrays of objects are [not supported](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/how-working-with-matlab-classes-is-different-for-code-generation.html) for code generation (see bullet 3 at that link). If you try:

```
[Circle(1), Circle(1)]
```

you'll get an error stating that fact:

> ??? Arrays of objects are not supported for code generation.

`matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` likely wouldn't have much utility in code generation without such support.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, my question did actually mix two issues: arrays of objects and Heterogeneous object types. There are situations where a single Heterogeneous object would be very helpful.  My solution to this is to make a autogenerated "combiner" class that internally switches between different classes.  It'd be a very nice feature to have Coder support this.

Comment: @Tony When you say "single Heterogeneous object" do you mean you want to be able to assign derived classes to a base class variable and then have dynamic dispatch based on the run time type? Similarly, would you want to be able to pass a derived object to a function taking a base object? Or did I miss the point?

Comment: That's exactly correct.  For instance I have an ABC of a generic file reader, and then multiple subclasses derived for each file format.  I'd like to be able to call the methods of the instantiated class and have it dispatch to the correct implementation based on which one I instantiate, but all the calls would remain unchanged.  I currently do this by means of an "aggregation" class, which is exactly the mess of switch statements you'd imagine, but encapsulates instances of each of the derived classes.

Comment: Thanks @Tony, I made a note of that too.